# Using uarial fonts in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, formatting

I'm new to LaTeX and I am having trouble getting the font `uarial` to work. I am using TeXLive the following looks for the font;

```
\IfFileExists{uarial.sty}
{
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{uarial}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
}
```

however I get the following error when running;

```
! Couldn't find Arial font.

 you may need to install 'nonfree' fonts on your system
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

As far as I am aware arial fonts are included in TeXLive, correct me if I am wrong. I have also installed nonfreefonts (I am using windows)

Is there another arial like font I can use that is included in TeXLive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: The second code you provided is the same as the first one. You may have something missing.

Comment: `uarial` is not part of TeX Live. You have to install it using [`getnonfreefonts`](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/).

Comment: What is »arial like«? Is Helvetica *arial like* enough. There are several Helvetica like fonts like TeX Gyre Heros.

Comment: also what do you mean by "exlatex" do you mean "xelatex"? The markup that you show is for pdflatex, if you are using xelatex you can use the windows system supplied Arial directly (assuming you are on Windows) but you should not use `fontenc` in that case

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question to include the error. Yes again sorry I meant XeLaTex. Helvetica would do in this case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using Windows, what should be used in place of `fontenc`?

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Arial}` then do not use `uarial` or `fontenc` packages which are not for xelatex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of XeTeX is to use the system fonts so you do not need to use clones supplied with TeXLive you can (if you wish) use the system Arial directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

Hello World
\end{document}
```

Comment: ah right makes sense now, thanks for clearing that up.